# How to learn whether a Snackbar button was pressed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, snackbar, itemtouchhelper

I have a Snackbar which is being opened when a user swipes on a RecyclerView element to delete it. And this Snackbar allows a user to undo his action. I know how to get an element of the RecyclerView back. But I also have a database(SQLite). It seems to me, the best way to do a removal from a detabase is to do it when I understand that a user doesn't press "undo". Otherwise I will need to make a removal and then adding.

I want to do something sort of this:

```
when (snackbar_button){
was_pressed -> adapter.restoreItem(cachedPosition, cachedItem)
was_not_pressed -> dbManager.removeItem(listArray[pos].id.toString())
}
```

This is my code on MainActivity:

```
val onSwipe = object : OnSwipe(this) {
    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        val cachedPosition = viewHolder.absoluteAdapterPosition
        val cachedItem = adapter.listArray[cachedPosition]
        when (direction) {
            ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT -> {
                adapter.removeItem(cachedPosition)

Snackbar.make(binding.rv, "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .apply {
                            setAction("Undo") {
                                adapter.restoreItem(cachedPosition, cachedItem)
                            }
                            show()
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My adapter:

```
fun removeItem(pos: Int) {
    listArray.removeAt(pos)
    notifyItemRemoved(pos)
    }

    fun restoreItem(pos: Int, listMain: ListItem) {
        listArray.add(pos, listMain)
        notifyItemInserted(pos)
  }
```

My code in DB to delete:

```
    fun removeItem(_id: String) {
        val id = BaseColumns._ID + "=$_id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `addCallback` function - you can add a [`BaseCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback) with an `onDismissed` function, where you're provided the reason for the dismissal. `DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION` means your *undo* button was clicked, anything else means the snackbar was swiped away, disappeared after a timeout, etc.

So you can do something like this:

```
Snackbar.make(binding.rv, "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .setAction("Undo") { // no need to do anything }
    .setCallback(object: BaseCallback<Snackbar> {
        override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar, event: Int) {
            // if the user didn't click Undo, delete the item
            if (event != DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) adapter.removeItem(cachedPosition)
        }
    }
    .show()
```

It would still be a good idea to remove the item from the list though, and restore it in the `setAction` lambda or in the `onDismissed` callback if the button was pressed. That way the user sees it disappear and reappear - deferring deletion is good for things like avoiding removing things from databases, where you don't want to touch the *real* data until you're sure.

You could still do that with what you have here:

```
// delete/hide it
adapter.removeItem(cachedPosition)

Snackbar.make(binding.rv, "Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .setAction("Undo") { // no need to do anything }
    .setCallback(object: BaseCallback<Snackbar> {
        override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar, event: Int) {
            // add the item back if they DID click Undo
            if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) adapter.restoreItem(cachedPosition, cachedItem)
            else // do something else if they didn't, like delete cachedItem from database
        }
    }
    .show()
```

---

Also if you're going to be accessing the `adapter` and managing the undo state externally like this, I'd make `removeItem` return the item that was removed (so you don't have to access the adapter's data list directly) and maybe rename `restoreItem` to `addItem` since technically you're inserting whatever you like at a position.

Really though, it would be better to keep the *last deleted item* internal to the adapter, so you can call *remove(position)* and *restore()* and let the adapter take care of the details and manage its own state. It's just cleaner and prevents bugs